# How do i make the transparent parts of the image white?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

hello there.

i have used image trace and parts of the image for some reason are transparent instead of black and white like the rest?

how do i get the transparent parts white?

as you can see from the image below the bits that disappear from the image when on the black background are transparent and i want them to be white?

i think a clipping mask may help but i dont know how to do it for a complex photo shape?

also tried live paint but some of the transparent areas would not let me paint others worked ok

thanks for youe help

=]

Answer (score 1):

I assume the original photo had a white background. (Impossible to tell from your posted image.) There's no way for the trace to tell the difference between what is background and what is dog. It merely sees white.

Draw white shapes and move them below the tracing.

(Clipping masks *aren't* going to help here really)

Comment: will try that now thank you, i notice after i expand the image there is a white box all the way around the dog when i delete the path all the way around the outside it also deletes some things that are included in the midle which are also part of the path

Comment: Yes, the "white box" is probably the background... since there's no dark areas between the background and the fog highlights, they are connected after the trace. Can't delete the "box" without also deleting parts of the dog highlights. You *might* be able to use a raster editor and add a bit of definition between the dog edges and the background and then try tracing again.

Comment: thanks scott i will just add white shapes underneath, im assuming i just send them layers behind the top layer then group and save ?

Comment: also instead of using shapes could i use paintbrush in some way?

Comment: Brushes in Illustrator are **not** like brushes in Photoshop.

Comment: ok thank you very much =]

Comment: It would be good if you upvoted his answer (the triangle on top left) and marked it as correct (because it is). This way others with the same or similar question will see this question as answered when they are searching the site.

Comment: @Kyle new users are actually restricted from voting somewhat. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1661/shouldnt-a-reputation-points-less-newbie-at-least-be-able-to-upvote-a-good-answ Can't upvote until you receive 2 upvotes, but can mark as correct.

Comment: I learn something new every day here- thanks

Comment: I do appreciate the prod though @Kyle `:)`